# How to add a call to a non-static class member function to the threadpool?

Tags: callback, c++-cli, threadpool, member-functions

I'm looking for this [stackoverflow: How to get Windows thread pool to call class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666259/how-to-get-windows-thread-pool-to-call-class-member-function) for C++/CLI:
I have a ref class with a member function (a copy of that function is static for testing purposes):

```
ref class CTest
{
public:
  static void testFuncStatic( System::Object^ stateInfo )
  {
    // do work;
  }
  void testFunction( System::Object^ stateInfo )
  {
    // do work;
  }
};
```

From main() I can easily add a call to the static function to the threadpool:

```
System::Threading::ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem (gcnew System::Threading::WaitCallback (&CTest::testFuncStatic));
```

But I don't want to call the static function (which is more or less an object-independent global function), I want to call the member function `testFunction()` for several instances of the class CTest.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++/CLI, you need to explicitly specify the object you want the delegate to call the function on.

```
ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(gcnew WaitCallback(this, &CTest::testFunction));
                                                 ^^^^
```

Comment: @ David:
`this` doesn't work because in main() there is no `this`, but you've put me on the right track, Thank you!! The solution: CTest^ ctest01 = gcnew CTest; ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem (gcnew WaitCallback (ctest01, &CTest::testFunction));

Answer (score 1):

You should not use thread pools in .NET. You should consider to use [System::Threading::Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx). This is an even more efficient way to use multiple "Tasks"...

Also be aware of the new "async" keyword in C#4.5. This helps a lot! So you should really consider to put the .NET part of your application into C#... and only use C++/CLI for InterOp scenarios.

Comment: The Task-Paralell-Library is more efficient that the "QueueUserWorkItem"... See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx Conclusion: Task is now the preferred way to queue work to the thread pool. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252217/is-there-a-difference-between-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-and-delegate-begininv  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200573/threadpool-queueuserworkitem-vs-task-factory-startnew

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CTest ^ ctest = gcnew CTest;
ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(gcnew WaitCallback(ctest, &CTest::testFunction));
                                                 ^^^^^
```

`WaitCallback(ctest` provides memory context to allocated object of `CTest`
`&CTest::testFunction));` provides memory shift to actual allocated function memory address of `testFunction`.
'Dynamic' functions are part of 'dynamic' class object.
This must be like that because of garbage collector.

Comment: Did you copy my comment from a 2 years old answer?

Comment: No! I just faced this problem. I did an experiment and after success I post this here. I read only answers, I did not see your comment. Can you post it as answer? I will remove my answer? I am sorry.

Comment: No, it's fine, you can keep yours.